# Google analytics for firebase visit log doesn't appear

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-analytics

Google analytics for Firebase is on my Next.js app. I deployed my site to Vercel. I can't see visit log in the first visit to my site in my Firebase console. But refresh my site, the log is well recorded.

app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app"
import Head from "next/head"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { analytics } from "../firebaseConfig"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const a = analytics
  return (
    <div>This is an example</div>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

firebaseConfig.ts

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASURMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const initAnalytics = (args: FirebaseApp) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return getAnalytics(args)
  } else {
    return null
  }
}
const analytics = initAnalytics(app)

export { app, analytics }
```

[image]

These sticks only updates when I visit my site AND refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using useEffect?

```js
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { analytics } from "../firebaseConfig";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    analytics();
  });
  return <div>This is an example</div>;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).